# List of supported architectures of Twilio Android SDK

Tags: android, twilio

I'm looking for the list of supported architectures of Twilio Android SDK.

I checked [changelog of the SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/changelog)
, and found following:

> CLIENT-2059 - The Client SDK now supports arm64-v8a and x86_64 architectures.
>
> CLIENT-2321 - MIPS architecture support has been removed.

But I haven't found the complete list. do you know where the list is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted to support and got the list at the moment:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- x86
- x86_64

They said that this info is missing from their public documentation, but they also said that they are going to update the docs.